# geometric proof for fibonacci numbers identity with sum of two squares

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

[Induction Proof: Fibonacci Numbers Identity with Sum of Two Squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300345/induction-proof-fibonacci-numbers-identity-with-sum-of-two-squares)

The link above gives the induction proof

does a geometric proof using the squares with Fibonacci length exist for this?