# show that $2^k|n\Longleftrightarrow 2^k|a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, divisibility

Let sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ such $a_{0}=0,a_{1}=1,a_{n}=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. show that
$$2^k|n\Longleftrightarrow 2^k|a_{n}$$

I try to find the $\{a_{n}\}$ closed form $$a_{n}=\dfrac{(1+\sqrt{2})^n-(1-\sqrt{2})^n}{2\sqrt{2}},$$Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Find a relation between $a_n$ and $a_{2n}$ and use induction.

Comment: How to find $a_{n}$ and $a_{2n}$ relation,can you explain detail?

Comment: Do you know a relation between $F_n$ and $F_{2n}$ for the Fibonacci numbers? It's very similar here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray}
a_n&=&\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}2^{i/2}-\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}2^{i/2}}{2^{3/2}}\\
&=&\frac{2\sum_{i=0}^{[n/2]}\binom{n}{2i+1}2^{(2i+1)/2}}{2^{3/2}}\\
&=&\sum_{i=0}^{[n/2]}\binom{n}{2i+1}2^{i}.
\end{eqnarray}
Since $n|\binom{n}{2i+1}$ for $i=0,1,\cdots [n/2]$,  we have if $2^k|n$, then $2^k|a_n$.

On the other hand, first note that
$$ a_n=n(1+m) $$
for some natural number $m\ge 1$ and hence if $2^k|a_n$, then $2^k|n$.

Comment: How to prove ：if $2^k|a_{n}$ then we have $2^k|n$

Comment: @geromty, I modified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use induction (such as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300345/induction-proof-fibonacci-numbers-identity-with-sum-of-two-squares)) or your closed form to show

$$a_{2n}=2a_{n}^2+2a_{n}a_{n-1} \Rightarrow 2a_{n}|a_{2n} $$

Thanks to @DanielFischer♦ .

Comment: can you prove $a_{2n}=2a^2_{n}+2a_{n}a_{n-1}?$

Comment: and How to prove this case: if $2^k|a_{n}$  then $2^k|n$

Comment: @geromty Use your closed Form. For your second question, as that in a seperate question.