# Computing $\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left(f(x)^k\right)$ where $k$ is a positive integer 

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Does anyone know a formula for the derivative $$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left(f(x)^k\right)$$ where $k$ is some positive integer?

I started trying to work it out but it got messy.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140185/are-there-ways-of-finding-the-n-th-derivative-of-a-function-without-computing

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261764/945479

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formule_de_Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno) to get 
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(g(x)^n)=\sum \frac{n!^2}{m_1!\dots m_n!(n-\sum_{j=1}^nm_j)!}g(x)^{n-\sum_{j=1}^nm_j}\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{g^{(j)}(x)}{j!}\right)^{m_j},$$
where the sum is taken over the $n$-uples $(m_1,\dots,m_n)$ of integer satisfying $\sum_{k=1}^nkm_k=n$.

(I changed the notations to be conform with the link)

Comment: I think it will be easier to compute that derivative directly...

Comment: @Norbert: which derivative do you mean?

Comment: I mean $(f^k(x))^{(k)}$. You answer is correct, but in practice it seems to me useless

Comment: Thank you, Davide. This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. It will be very useful.

Answer (score 7):

As a probable illustration of Davide Giraudo's powerful answer (+1) you may get the following result :

$
\begin{array} {r|cccccccc}
k\\
\hline
1&1f'\\
2&2f''f&2f'^2\\
3&3f'''f^2&18f''ff'&6f'^3\\
4&4f''''f^3&48f'''f^2f'&36f''^2f^2&144f'^2f''f&24f'^4\\
5&5f'''''f^4&100f''''f^3f'&200f'''f^3f''&600 f'''f^2f'^2&900f^2f'f''^2&1200ff'^3f''&120f'^5\\
\end{array}
$

This triangle appears as sequence [OEIS A049009](https://oeis.org/A049009) titled "Number of functions from a set to itself such that the sizes of the pre-images of the individual elements in the range form the n-th partition in Abramowitz and Stegun order"

In fact this is a product of [multinomials coefficients](https://oeis.org/A036038) and ['number of multisets associated with least integer of each prime signature'](https://oeis.org/A035206) (the second one shifted by $2$ I think). Perhaps that this will help a little to interpret Davide's general answer (I have not much hope for further simplification...)

Hoping it helped anyway,

Answer (score 7):

As a reformulation of Davide's answer, the $k$-th derivative of $f(x)^k$ is most easily expressed using the [partial Bell polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Fa.C3.A0_di_Bruno.27s_formula):

$$\frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm dx^k}f(x)^k=\sum_{j=1}^k j!\binom{k}{j} f(x)^{k-j} \mathrm{B}_{k,j}(f^\prime(x),f^{\prime\prime}(x),\cdots,f^{(k-j+1)}(x))$$

This construction is most convenient if the computing environment you are using supports partial Bell polynomials (e.g. *Mathematica*).

Answer (score 2):

After Raymond's explication of Davide's Faa di Bruno-formula I decomposed it in an even more memorizable form. Example  k=4
$$ \begin{eqnarray}  {(f^4)^{(4)}\over 4! \cdot 4! } &=&
  {{ f^{(0)}\over 0!} { f^{(0)}\over 0!}{ f^{(0)}\over 0!} \over 3! }{{ f^{(4)}\over 4!}  \over 1! }  \\ \\
 &+ & {{ f^{(0)}\over 0!} { f^{(0)}\over 0!} \over 2! }{{ f^{(1)}\over 1!}  \over 1! } {{ f^{(3)}\over 3!}  \over 1! } \\ \\
 &+ & {{ f^{(0)}\over 0!} { f^{(0)}\over 0!} \over 2! }{{ f^{(2)}\over 2!}{ f^{(2)}\over 2!}  \over 2! } 
 &+ & {{ f^{(0)}\over 0!}  \over 1! } {{ f^{(1)}\over 1!} { f^{(1)}\over 1!} \over 2! }{{ f^{(2)}\over 2!}  \over 1! } \\ \\
 &+ & {{ f^{(1)}\over 1!} { f^{(1)}\over 1!} { f^{(1)}\over 1!}  { f^{(1)}\over 1!}\over 4! } \\ \\
 \end{eqnarray} $$
The key for that decomposition is, that for some *k* we need *k* factors in each summand. Then the sum of all derivation-indices (with their multiplicity!) must also equal *k*. A *j*-fold multiplicity of a factor must be compensated by a *j!* in the denominator.
If we write 
$\displaystyle  [k]= { f^{(k)}\over k! } $ and $ \displaystyle [k \times j] = { [k]^j \over j!} $  we can denote it even more compact:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}{(f^4)^{(4)} \over 4!4! }&=& [0 \times 3][4 \times 1] \\ &+& [0 \times 2][1 \times 1][3 \times 1] \\ &+& [0 \times 2][2 \times 2] + [0 \times 1][1 \times 2][2 \times 1] \\
&+&[1 \times 4] \end{eqnarray}
$$ where, if we take the brackets as products and the terms as sums then each term has the sum k. It is a simple mechanic to write down the terms by hand for some small k, even for $k=10$ or so this should be doable with paper and pen.

Comment: Thanks for the very nice and clear rewriting Gottfried!

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: :-) After getting this I did a similar explanation on the wikipedia-page for the Faà di Bruno, see http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula&pe=1&#Explication_via_an_example . Perhaps it is a much general useful translation, to use the factorially scaled derivatives and factorially scaled multiplicities of the factors in similar applications ...