# How can I determine a general formula for the nth derivative of any continuous function $f(x)$ differentiable at least $n$ times?

Tags: derivatives

I know how to do it with easier functions, but is there a universal method which can be applied to all continuous functions differentiable at least $n$ times(introduced to in a second year calculus class)?

I can do it for easy ones like $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, but $\sin(x^2)$ and $\tan(x)$ and $\ln(1+x^2)$ are proving to be very difficult.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are four parts in this answer.

###### Part I

The Faa di Bruno formula (see Theorem 11.4 in the book [1] and Theorem C on page 139 in the monograph [2] below) can be described in terms of the Bell polynomials of the second kind $B_{n,k}\bigl(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_{n-k+1}\bigr)$ by
\begin{equation}\label{Bruno-Bell-Polynomial}\tag{1}
\frac{\textrm{d}^n}{\textrm{d}x^n}f\circ h(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nf^{(k)}(h(x)) B_{n,k}\bigl(h'(x),h''(x),\dotsc,h^{(n-k+1)}(x)\bigr), \quad n\ge0.
\end{equation}
In Theorem 5.1 of the paper [3] and Section 3 of the paper [4] below, it was found that
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-x-1-0-eq}\tag{2}
B_{n,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)
=\frac{1}{2^{n-k}}\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k-n}, \quad n\ge k\ge0,
\end{equation}
where $\binom{0}{0}=1$ and $\binom{p}{q}=0$ for $q>p\ge0$. Consequently, as an example, we have
\begin{equation*}
\Bigl(e^{x^2}\Bigr)^{(n)} =e^{x^2}\frac{n!}{(2x)^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k}{n-k}\frac{(2x)^{2k}}{k!}, \quad n\ge0.
\end{equation*}
Similarly, by virtue of the formulas \eqref{Bruno-Bell-Polynomial} and \eqref{Bell-x-1-0-eq}, general formulas for the $n$th derivatives of the functions $\sin\bigl(x^2\bigr)$ and $\ln\bigl(1+x^2\bigr)$ can be derived readily as
\begin{equation}\tag{+}
\bigl[\sin\bigl(x^2\bigr)\bigr]^{(n)}
=\frac{n!}{(2x)^n}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{k}{n-k}\frac{(2x)^{2k}}{k!} \sin\biggl(x^2+\frac{k\pi}{2}\biggr), \quad n\ge0
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\tag{#}
\bigl[\ln\bigl(1+x^2\bigr)\bigr]^{(n)}
=\frac{n!}{(2x)^n}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{k}{n-k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\frac{(2x)^{2k}}{(1+x^2)^{k}}, \quad n\ge1.
\end{equation}

###### Part II

In Theorem 1.2 of the paper [5] below, it was derived that
\begin{multline}\label{bell-sin-eq}\tag{3}
B_{n,k}\biggl(-\sin x,-\cos x,\sin x,\cos x,\dotsc, \cos\biggl[x+\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr]\biggr)\\
=\frac{(-1)^k\cos^kx}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{k}{\ell}\frac{(-1)^\ell}{(2\cos x)^\ell}
\sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n \cos\biggl[(2q-\ell)x+\frac{n\pi}2\biggr]
\end{multline}
and
\begin{multline}\label{bell-sin=ans}\tag{4}
B_{n,k}\biggl(\cos x,-\sin x,-\cos x,\sin x,\dotsc, \sin\biggl[x+\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr]\biggr)\\
=\frac{(-1)^k\sin^{k}x}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{k}{\ell}\frac1{(2\sin x)^{\ell}}
\sum_{q=0}^\ell(-1)^q\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n \cos\biggl[(2q-\ell)x+\frac{(n-\ell)\pi}2\biggr]
\end{multline}
for $n\ge k\ge0$. Since $\sin\bigl(x\pm\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)=\pm\cos x$ and $\cos\bigl(x\pm\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)=\mp\sin x$, the formulas \eqref{bell-sin-eq} and \eqref{bell-sin=ans} are equivalent to each other.
These two formulas \eqref{bell-sin-eq} and \eqref{bell-sin=ans} can be applied to establish general formulas of the $n$th derivatives for functions of the types $f(\sin x)$ and $f(\cos x)$, such as $\sin^\alpha x$, $\cos^\alpha x$, $\sec^\alpha x$, $\csc^\alpha x$, $e^{\pm\sin x}$, $e^{\pm\cos x}$, $\ln\cos x$, $\ln\sin x$, $\ln\sec x$, $\ln\csc x$, $\sin\sin x$, $\cos\sin x$, $\sin\cos x$, $\cos\cos x$, $\tan x=-(\ln\cos x)'$, and $\cot x=(\ln \sin x)'$, if the general formula for the $n$th derivative of $f$ is computable.

###### Part III

Define the falling factorial of $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ by
\begin{equation*}%\label{Fall-Factorial-Dfn-Eq}
\langle\alpha\rangle_n=
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)=
\begin{cases}
\alpha(\alpha-1)\dotsm(\alpha-n+1), & n\ge1;\\
1,& n=0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
In Remark 3.1 on page 88 in the paper [17] below, the formula
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-1-lambda}\tag{5}
B_{n,k}\Biggl(1, 1-\lambda, (1-\lambda)(1-2\lambda),\dotsc, \prod_{\ell=0}^{n-k}(1-\ell\lambda)\Biggr)
=\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \sum_{\ell=0}^k (-1)^{\ell} \binom{k}{\ell} \prod_{q=0}^{n-1}(\ell-q\lambda)
\end{equation}
for $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n\ge k\ge0$ was concluded. In Theorem 2.1 on page 165 in the paper [11] below, it was discovered that
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-fall-Eq}\tag{6}
B_{n,k}(\langle\alpha\rangle_1, \langle\alpha\rangle_2, \dotsc,\langle\alpha\rangle_{n-k+1})
=\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k}(-1)^{\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}\langle\alpha\ell\rangle_n
\end{equation}
for $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n\ge k\ge0$. These two formulas \eqref{Bell-1-lambda} and \eqref{Bell-fall-Eq} are equivalent to each other.

By virtue of the Faa di Bruno formula \eqref{Bruno-Bell-Polynomial} and any one of the formulas \eqref{Bell-1-lambda} and \eqref{Bell-fall-Eq}, one can establish general formulas of the $n$th derivatives for functions of the type $f(x^\alpha)$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, such as $e^{x^\alpha}$, $\sin[(a+bx)^\alpha]$, and $\ln(1\pm x^\alpha)$, if the $n$th derivative of the function $f$ is computable.

###### Part IV

The $n$th derivative formulas for the tangent function $\tan x=\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and the cotangent function $\cot x=\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}$ can also be computed by the formula
\begin{equation}\label{Sitnik-Bourbaki}\tag{7}
\frac{\textrm{d}^k}{\textrm{d}z^k}\biggl(\frac{u}{v}\biggr)
=\frac{(-1)^k}{v^{k+1}}
\begin{vmatrix}
u & v & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
u' & v' & v & \dotsm & 0\\
u'' & v'' & 2v' & \dotsm & 0\\
\dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \ddots & \dotsm\\
u^{(k-1)} & v^{(k-1)} & \binom{k-1}1v^{(k-2)} &  \dots & v\\
u^{(k)} & v^{(k)} & \binom{k}1v^{(k-1)} & \dots & \binom{k}{k-1}v'
\end{vmatrix}.
\end{equation}
For details on the formula \eqref{Sitnik-Bourbaki}, please refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261705/945479.

The texts in the first three parts above are extracted and modified from Sections 1.3, 1.4, and 1.6 in the paper [6] below.

References

1. C. A. Charalambides, *Enumerative Combinatorics*, CRC Press Series on Discrete Mathematics and its Applications. Chapman & Hall/CRC, Boca Raton, FL, 2002.
2. L. Comtet, *Advanced Combinatorics: The Art of Finite and Infinite Expansions*, Revised and Enlarged Edition, D. Reidel Publishing Co., 1974; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-010-2196-8.
3. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Art. 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
4. F. Qi and M.-M. Zheng, *Explicit expressions for a family of the Bell polynomials and applications*, Appl. Math. Comput. **258** (2015), 597--607; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.02.027.
5. F. Qi, *Derivatives of tangent function and tangent numbers*, Appl. Math. Comput. **268** (2015), 844--858; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.06.123.
6. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
7. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Series expansions of powers of arcsine, closed forms for special values of Bell polynomials, and series representations of generalized logsine functions*, AIMS Mathematics **6** (2021), no. 7, 7494--7517; available online at https://doi.org/10.3934/math.2021438.
8. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Maclaurin's series expansions for positive integer powers of inverse (hyperbolic) sine and tangent functions, closed-form formula of specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representation of generalized logsine function*, Applicable Analysis and Discrete Mathematics **16** (2022), no. 2, in press; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM210401017G.
9. Feng Qi and Dongkyu Lim, *Closed formulas for special Bell polynomials by Stirling numbers and associate Stirling numbers*, Publications de l'Institut Mathematique (Beograd) **108** (2020), no. 122, 131--136; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/PIM2022131Q.
10. Feng Qi, Pierpaolo Natalini, and Paolo Emilio Ricci, *Recurrences of Stirling and Lah numbers via second kind Bell polynomials*, Discrete Mathematics Letters **3** (2020), 31--36.
11. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Bai-Ni Guo, *Closed formulas and identities for the Bell polynomials and falling factorials*, Contributions to Discrete Mathematics **15** (2020), no. 1, 163--174; available online at https://doi.org/10.11575/cdm.v15i1.68111.
12. Feng Qi, Dongkyu Lim, and Bai-Ni Guo, *Explicit formulas and identities for the Bell polynomials and a sequence of polynomials applied to differential equations*, Revista de la Real Academia de Ciencias Exactas Fisicas y Naturales Serie A Matematicas **113** (2019), no. 1, 1--9; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s13398-017-0427-2.
13. Feng Qi, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Notes on two kinds of special values for the Bell polynomials of the second kind*, Miskolc Mathematical Notes **20** (2019), no. 1, 465--474; available online at https://doi.org/10.18514/MMN.2019.2635.
14. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, and Bai-Ni Guo, *Some identities for a sequence of unnamed polynomials connected with the Bell polynomials*, Revista de la Real Academia de Ciencias Exactas Fisicas y Naturales Serie A Matematicas **113** (2019), no. 2, 557--567; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s13398-018-0494-z.
15. A.-M. Xu and G.-D. Cen, *Closed formulas for computing higher-order derivatives of functions involving exponential functions*, Appl. Math. Comput. **270** (2015), 136--141; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.08.051.
16. A.-M. Xu and Z.-D. Cen, *Some identities involving exponential functions and Stirling numbers and applications*, J. Comput. Appl. Math. **260** (2014), 201--207; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2013.09.077.
17. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *Viewing some ordinary differential equations from the angle of derivative polynomials*, Iranian Journal of Mathematical Sciences and Informatics **16** (2021), no. 1, 77--95; available online at https://doi.org/10.29252/ijmsi.16.1.77.

Answer (score 1):

The functions that you list, $\sin(x^2)$ and $\tan(x)$ and $\ln(1+x^2)$ are indeed infinitely many times differentiable, you just need to learn differentiation rules, e.g. product, quotient, chain, power rule, etc, and differentiate these functions as many times  as you wish (and, perhaps, in some cases find a general formula for the $n$th derivative). 
Well, for some functions it will indeed be difficult to find a general formula. You may take the first few derivatives, and try to guess the formula for the $n$th derivative in each specific case. If you guess is correct, then you may prove it by induction.

Comment: "as Suzu indicated there are continuous functions that are not differentiable" - he has already fixed that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no universal method for differentiating functions, if you want to get other functions out. If you reduce it to a Taylor series, then you can do that, but the output of the process is another Taylor series.

Answer (score 0):

Find the Taylor series, and use that to evaluate at the nth value?

Comment: To find the taylor series, I would need to evaluate the nth derivative in the first place...

Comment: Not necessarily, you can work out Taylor series of many functions without differentiation.

Comment: Try substitutions of the Taylor series of known polynomials, and use that the find the nth derivative?

Answer (score 0):

Consider e.g. the [Elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), the [Liouvillian functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouvillian_function), some of the [Special functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions) and/or algebraic operations.

The set of the function terms of the Elementary functions is closed regarding differentiation.
The set of the function terms of the Liouvillian functions is closed regarding differentiation.

Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ denote variables.

Some functions have an $n$-th derivative that is equal to its $m$-th derivative.

There are rules for the $n$-th derivative of some elementary standard functions. See e.g. Bronshtein/Semendyayev/Musiol/Mühlig: Handbook of Mathematics, Springer, table 6.3.

As for the first derivative, there are higher sum rule, higher factor rule, higher product rule ([General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)) and higher chain rule ([Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)) to calculate the $n$-th derivatives.

You have to build your given function term hierarchically from smaller function terms and algebraic operations (unary or multiary algebraic functions) to apply the higher differentiation rules above.

$sin(x^2)$ and $ln(1+x^2)$ can be represented as compositions.
$tan(x)=\frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}$ can be represented as quotient.
Apply higher chain rule and higher quotient rule respectively and hope that the smaller function terms have known general terms for their n-th derivatives.

In 2012, I wrote a still unpublished article "On partial Bell polynomials for the higher derivatives of composed functions".

Comment: Isn't my answer worth to be upvoted?