# Proving a Challenging Triple Summation Identity involving Bell Polynomials

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, derivatives, summation

### I need to prove that the following expression is true:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}[fg]\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c\}} \Phi(k,c,j) f^{k-c-j} g^{c-j} \lambda(k,c,x) = 
\\
(fg')^{n+1}\sum_{c=2}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,n-c+1\}} \Phi(n+1,c,j) \left(\frac{f'g}{g'f}\right)^c
 \left(\frac{1}{fg}\right)^j
\\
+\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c\}} \Phi(k,c,j)f^{k-c-j-1}g^{c-j-1}
\\
\left(-(k-c-j)f'g \lambda(k,c,x)
+ fgf'\lambda(k-1,c-1,x)
\\
-(c-j)g'f\lambda(k,c,x) + fgg'\lambda(k-1,c,x)\right)
\end{align*}
Where the following is true:
$$
\Phi(k,c,j) = {c \choose j}\frac{(k-c)!}{(k-c-j)!}
$$
$$
\lambda(k,c,x) = \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} {n \choose l} B_{n-l,c}^f(x) B_{l,k-c}^g(x)
$$
Where $B_{n,k}^f(x) = B_{n,k}(f'(x),f''(x),\ldots,f^{(n-k+1)}(x))$ which is the partial Bell Polynomial. More information can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Combinatorial_meaning). Also note that the following properties are used:
$$
B_{n,k}^f(x) = 0 \quad\quad\quad\quad (k >n)
$$
$$
B_{n,0}^f(x) = 0
$$

### My Attempt

What I tried to do was factor all the $\lambda(k,c,x)$ into like terms:
\begin{align}
f'\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c\}} \Phi(k,c,j)f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \lambda(k-1,c-1,x)
\\
= f'g\sum_{c=1}^{n-2} \sum_{k=c+2}^n \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c+1,k-c-1\}} \Phi(k,c+1,j)f^{k-c-j-1}g^{c-j} \lambda(k-1,c,x)
\\
=f'g\sum_{c=1}^{n-2} \sum_{k=c+1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c+1,k-c\}} \Phi(k+1,c+1,j)f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \lambda(k,c,x)
\end{align}
Also:
\begin{align}
g'\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c\}} \Phi(k,c,j)f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \lambda(k-1,c,x)
\\
=g'f \sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c+1\}} \Phi(k+1,c,j)f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \lambda(k,c,x)
\end{align}
Now we have:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c\}} \Phi(k,c,j) f^{k-c-j} g^{c-j} \lambda(k,c,x) = 
\\
(fg')^{n+1}\sum_{c=2}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,n-c+1\}} \Phi(n+1,c,j) \left(\frac{f'g}{g'f}\right)^c
 \left(\frac{1}{fg}\right)^j
\\
-g'f\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c\}} \Phi(k,c,j)(c-j)f^{k-c-j-1}g^{c-j-1}\lambda(k,c,x)
\\
-f'g\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c\}} \Phi(k,c,j)(k-c-j) f^{k-c-j-1}g^{c-j-1}\lambda(k,c,x)
\\
 + g'f \sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c+1\}} \Phi(k+1,c,j)f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \lambda(k,c,x)
\\
 + f'g\sum_{c=1}^{n-2} \sum_{k=c+1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c+1,k-c\}} \Phi(k+1,c+1,j)f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \lambda(k,c,x)
\end{align*}
Now i will match up the bounds on the triple summations that have like terms:
\begin{align}
\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c\}} \Phi(k,c,j) f^{k-c-j} g^{c-j} \lambda(k,c,x) = 
\\
(fg')^{n+1}\sum_{c=2}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,n-c+1\}} \Phi(n+1,c,j) \left(\frac{f'g}{g'f}\right)^c
 \left(\frac{1}{fg}\right)^j
\\
-g'f\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c\}} \Phi(k,c,j)(c-j)f^{k-c-j-1}g^{c-j-1}\lambda(k,c,x)
\\
-f'g\sum_{c=1}^{n-2} \sum_{k=c+1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c\}} \Phi(k,c,j)(k-c-j) f^{k-c-j-1}g^{c-j-1}\lambda(k,c,x)
\\
 + g'f \sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c+1\}} \Phi(k+1,c,j)f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \lambda(k,c,x)
\\
 + f'g\sum_{c=1}^{n-2} \sum_{k=c+1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c+1,k-c\}} \Phi(k+1,c+1,j)f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \lambda(k,c,x)
\\
 - f'g \sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,n-c\}} \Phi(n,c,j)(n-c-1)f^{n-c-j-1}g^{c-j-1} \lambda(n,c,x)
\\
+g'f \sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^1 \Phi(c+1,c,j)f^{-j}g^{c-j}\lambda(c,c,x)
\end{align}
Now notice on the terms where $f^{k-c-j-1} g^{c-j-1}$, we can eliminate this problem by shifting the $j$ index:
\begin{align}
\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c\}} \Phi(k,c,j) f^{k-c-j} g^{c-j} \lambda(k,c,x) = 
\\
(fg')^{n+1}\sum_{c=2}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,n-c+1\}} \Phi(n+1,c,j) \left(\frac{f'g}{g'f}\right)^c
 \left(\frac{1}{fg}\right)^j
\\
-g'f\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{min\{c+1,k-c+1\}} \Phi(k,c,j-1)(c-j+1)f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j}\lambda(k,c,x)
\\
-f'g\sum_{c=1}^{n-2} \sum_{k=c+1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^{min\{c+1,k-c+1\}} \Phi(k,c,j-1)(k-c-j+1) f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j}\lambda(k,c,x)
\\
 + g'f \sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c+1\}} \Phi(k+1,c,j)f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \lambda(k,c,x)
\\
 + f'g\sum_{c=1}^{n-2} \sum_{k=c+1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c+1,k-c\}} \Phi(k+1,c+1,j)f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j} \lambda(k,c,x)
\\
 - f'g \sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,n-c\}} \Phi(n,c,j)(n-c-1)f^{n-c-j-1}g^{c-j-1} \lambda(n,c,x)
\\
+g'f \sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^1 \Phi(c+1,c,j)f^{-j}g^{c-j}\lambda(c,c,x)
\end{align}
Now to collect like terms:
\begin{align}
\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c\}} \Phi(k,c,j) f^{k-c-j} g^{c-j} \lambda(k,c,x) = 
\\
(fg')^{n+1}\sum_{c=2}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,n-c+1\}} \Phi(n+1,c,j) \left(\frac{f'g}{g'f}\right)^c
 \left(\frac{1}{fg}\right)^j
 + g'f \sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c+1}^{n-1} \lambda(k,c,x)
\left(\sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,k-c+1\}}f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j}\Phi(k+1,c,j)
\\
-\sum_{j=1}^{min\{c+1,k-c+1\}}f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j}\Phi(k,c,j-1)(c-j+1)\right)
\\
 + f'g\sum_{c=1}^{n-2} \sum_{k=c+1}^{n-1}  \lambda(k,c,x)
 \left(\sum_{j=0}^{min\{c+1,k-c\}}f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j}\Phi(k+1,c+1,j) 
\\
- \sum_{j=1}^{min\{c+1,k-c+1\}}f^{k-c-j}g^{c-j}\Phi(k,c,j-1)(k-c-j+1)\right)
\\
 - f'g \sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{min\{c,n-c\}} \Phi(n,c,j)(n-c-1)f^{n-c-j-1}g^{c-j-1} \lambda(n,c,x)
\\
+g'f \sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^1 \Phi(c+1,c,j)f^{-j}g^{c-j}\lambda(c,c,x)
\end{align}
Once I get to this point I have absolutely no clue what else I can do with the summation bounds in order to simplify more.

### What is the expression for?

The expression is simply a part of an expression that calculated the Complete Bell Polynomial of a product. The expression for a complete bell polynomial of a product is:
$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}[e^{fg}] = e^{fg}B_n^{fg}(x)
$$
Where
$$
B_n^{fg}(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n B_{n,k}^{fg}(x)
$$

Comment: tldr, maybe you can provide a context, what does this count? Otherwise it seems unlikely that someone reads and checks everything...

Comment: This is a truly big problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261764/945479