# nth derivative of a finite amount of composite functions

Tags: calculus

I was curious to see whether or not there is a formula for the $n$th derivative of $k$ composite functions. If $F(x)=(f_1\circ f_2\circ...\circ f_k(x))$ then is there a formula for

$$\frac{d^n} {dx^n}(F(x)).$$

For the $n$th derivative of two composite functions we use Faa di Bruno's rule, or

$$\frac{d^n} {dx^n}(f(g(x)) =\sum \frac {n!} {m_1! 1!^{m_1} ... m_n! n!^{m_n}} \cdot f^{(m_1 + ... + m_n)} (g(x)) \prod_{i=1}^{n}(g^{(i)}(x))^{m_i}, $$

where the sum is over all the values of $m_1,...,m_n$ such that $m_1+2m_2+...+nm_n=n$.

Also, for the first derivative of $k$ composite functions, user Yangzhe Lau gave me the formula

$$F'(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}f'_i(f_{i+1}\circ f_{i+2} \circ \cdot \cdot\cdot\circ f_k(x)).$$

Therefore, is there a formula for that essentially combines these two, I suppose.

Comment: Of course there is but do *you* want to be the one who has to write it down?

Comment: I'd be delighted to write it down if someone can evaluate the formula. @TooOldForMath

Comment: By writing it down I of course also meant "finding it", i.e. figuring out how to write down what we all know anyway.

Comment: My attempts to write it down have been pitiful. @ TooOldForMath

Comment: I don't understand your question here, Do you want a proof for Faa di Bruno's formula  ?

Comment: No. di Bruno's formula gives the nth derivative of a composition of two functions. I am curious to see whether or not there is a formula for the nth derivative of a finite (greater than two) composition of functions.

Comment: I'll look through the large number of papers I happened to have collected on the topic of $n$'th derivatives of products, quotients, and compositions this weekend and see if anything turns up. I posted about some of these in comments I made at [this StackExchange question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140185/are-there-ways-of-finding-the-n-th-derivative-of-a-function-without-computing), but I don't have access to copies of any of these papers at the moment.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any published explicit expression for the $n$'th derivative of a composition of $k$ many functions. However, I did come across a book I got a few years ago that I'd fogotten about, a book you might be interested in looking at if this sort of stuff really interests you: Isaac Joachim Schwatt, [**An Introduction to the Operations with Series**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0006AXDOE) (1924; reprinted by Chelsea in 1962, [Bull. AMS review](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183486862)). Chapter 1 (about 26 pages) deals entirely with the $n$'th derivative of a composition.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the following it is easier to begin with functions which have no constant term, so say 
$$ \begin{eqnarray} 
f_1(x) &=&a_1 x + b_1 x^2 + c_1 x^3 + ... \\
f_2(x) &=&a_2 x + b_2 x^2 + c_2 x^3 + ... \\
... \\
f_n(x) &= &a_n x + b_n x^2 + c_n x^3 + ... \\
\end{eqnarray} $$
This allows to use the concept of ["Carleman"- or "Bell"-matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix) for the composition of functions.
We define a Carlemanmatrix for the above functions, for instance $F_k$ for $f_k(x)$ such that the columns contain the coefficients of the consecutive powers of$f_k$ beginning with that of $f_k(x)^0, f_k(x),f_k(x)^2,...$ where it is obvious that we deal with infinite sized matrices! But the matrices come out to be triangular so we can later operate with them. For instance , $F_1$ looks like
$$ F_1 =  \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & . & . & . & . & \cdots \\ 
 0 & a_1 & . & . & . & \cdots \\ 
 0 & b_1 & a_1^2 & . & . & \cdots \\ 
 0 & c_1 & 2 a_1 b_1 & a_1^3 & . & \cdots \\ 
 0 & d_1 & b_1^2+2 c_1 a_1 & 3 a_1^2 b_1 & a_1^4& \cdots \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \vdots & \ddots
 \end{bmatrix} $$
We see in the columns the coefficients of the powers of the formal power series of $f_1$.
Now with a "Vandermonde"-vector $V(x)=[1,x,x^2,x^3,...]$ the dotproduct $V(x) \cdot F_1 $ gives the evaluation of the function $f_1(x)$ ***and*** all of its (nonnegative) powers:
$$ V(x) \cdot F_1 = [1,f(x),f(x)^2,f(x)^3,...] = V(f(x)) $$
The clue is here, that the result is again of the "Vandermonde"-type and that we can  thus proceed with the next function and so on ...

Then the composition of the functions $g(x) = f_3 \circ f_2 \circ f_1 (x)$ has simply the Carlemanmatrix $G$ which is
$$ G = F_1 \cdot F_2 \cdot F_3 $$

To exercise with this it is -in the software Pari/GP- easy to define appropriate vector- and even matrix-functions for some finite size $n$:

```
f1(x)= 'a1*x + 'b1*x^2+'c1*x^3+'d1*x^4+ O(x^5)      \\ actually you would  
f2(x)= 'a2*x + 'b2*x^2+'c2*x^3+'d2*x^4+ O(x^5)      \\ give some concrete values  
f3(x)= 'a3*x + 'b3*x^2+'c3*x^3+'d3*x^4+ O(x^5)      \\ for the symbols 'a,'b,...  
V(x,n)=vector(n,r,x^(r-1))     
Carleman(x,n)=matrix(n,n,r,c,...)
```

where the latter function can accept a function written as truncated powerseries and then

```
F1 = Carleman(f1(x))
F2 = Carleman(f2(x))
F3 = Carleman(f3(x))
G = F1 * F2 * F3 
print(Ser(G[,2]))  \\ shows the notation of the power series of g(x)
```

and approximate results can be computed if the series converge well and the size of the matrices and vectors are sufficient just by

```
   x = 0.5   \\ give some initial value which gives reasonable approximation
   y1 = V(x )*F1[,2])     \\ shows evaluation of f1 at some value x       
   y2 = V(y1)*F2[,2])    \\ shows evaluation of f2 at the value y1=f1(x)       
   y3 = V(y2)*F3[,2])    \\ shows evaluation of f3 at the value y2=f2(f1(x))       
   g = V(x) * G[,2]    \\ g and y3 should be identical
```

*(If you want to keep things symbolic then reduce the matrix-size to 4 or 5 - the composition creates huge stuff of terms!)*

It is hopeless to try to write out the resulting coefficients for an indeterminate number of functions $f_k(x)$, but for the composition of, say 3 functions, the top left part of $G = F_1 \cdot F_2 \cdot F_3$ looks like
$$ \Tiny \begin{array} {} 
 1 & . & . & . \\ 
 0 & a_3 a_2 a_1 & . & . \\ 
 0 & a_3 a_2 b_1+a_3 a_1^2 b_2+a_2^2 a_1^2 b_3 & a_3^2 a_2^2 a_1^2 & . \\ 
 0 & (2 a_3 a_1 b_2+2 a_2^2 a_1 b_3) b_1+2 a_2 a_1^3 b_3 b_2+(c_3 a_2^3+c_2 a_3) a_1^3+c_1 a_3 a_2 & 2 a_3^2 a_2^2 a_1 b_1+2 a_3^2 a_2 a_1^3 b_2+2 a_3 a_2^3 a_1^3 b_3 & a_3^3 a_2^3 a_1^3
 \end{array}
$$
The n'th derivatives of $g(x)$ are now in the second column, for instance
$ \displaystyle \qquad g'(x) = a_3 a_2 a_1 \\
\qquad g''(x)/2! = a_3 a_2 b_1+a_3 a_1^2 b_2+a_2^2 a_1^2 b_3  \\
\qquad g'''(x)/3! = (2 a_3 a_1 b_2+2 a_2^2 a_1 b_3) b_1+2 a_2 a_1^3 b_3 b_2+(c_3 a_2^3+c_2 a_3) a_1^3+c_1 a_3 a_2  \\
$

---

*Additional remark: in the case of self-composition of functions, in this case all $f_k(x)$ are the same we have functional iteration and for this I've done a scheme for indeterminate iteration-height (but this was not asked for in the OP)*