# Is there an *actual* formula for the nth derivative of any number of composites?

Tags: calculus

I was wondering recently about a generalized rule for the nth derivative of k composite functions, just like in the link below that I found on stackexchange.

For some reason however, the OP here [nth derivative of a finite amount of composite functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657166/nth-derivative-of-a-finite-amount-of-composite-functions) 
chose an answer that doesn't actually answer this question, there's no closed form of anything anywhere in what they picked to be the answer. So is there any material on what the actual answer is? At least for the same iterated function if not a composite of any combination of function?