# Order of derivatives in automatic differentiation

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, gradient-descent, neural-networks

I did this derivation and want to know if it is correct. Basically, we want to know the gradient of $f$ at the point $g(M)$.

Let $\Psi \equiv g \circ f$ be the function representing the forward pass and let $f: \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ represent the part of the forward pass we are interested in, where $m$ is the batch size and $n$ the array length. Assume we can decompose $f$ into $d \in \mathbb{N}^+$ functions $f_1, f_2, \dots, f_d$:
\begin{equation*}
    f \equiv f_d \circ f_{d-1} \circ \dots \circ f_1
\end{equation*}

Now define $f^i$ for $i \in \{0, 1, \dots, d\}$, where $f_0(M) := M$:
\begin{equation*}
    f^i := f_i \circ f_{i - 1} \circ \dots \circ f_1 \circ f_0
\end{equation*}

Defininig $f_0$ as the identity function is just a trick to simplify the below expression. Please note that we already know $\nabla g(f(M))$ as that is one of the inputs to our backward pass and since we did the forward pass, we also calculated all the $f^i$, $i \in \{0, 1, \dots, d\}$.

Now let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. It follows using the chain rule:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \nabla (g \circ f)(M)
         & = \nabla g(f(M)) \cdot \nabla f^d(M)                                                                   \\
         & = \nabla g(f(M)) \cdot \nabla f_d(f^{d-1}(M)) \cdot \nabla f^{d-1}(M)                                  \\
         & = \nabla g(f(M)) \cdot \nabla f_d(f^{d-1}(M)) \cdot \nabla f_{d-1}(f^{d-2}(M)) \cdot \nabla f^{d-2}(M) \\
         & \;\;\vdots                                                                                       \\
         & = \nabla g(f(M)) \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{d-1} \left(\nabla f_{d-i+1}(f^{d-i}(M))\right) \cdot \nabla f^1(M) \\
         &= \underbrace{\nabla g(f(M))}_{\text{known}} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{d} \nabla f_{d-i+1}(\underbrace{f^{d-i}(M)}_{\text{known}})
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

My derivation implies that the order of calculating the $\nabla f_i(f^{i-1}(M))$ is irrelevant. However, the technique to do automatic differentiation is called backward pass, and as I understand it, you always use the previous derivative as an input to the next one, taking derivatives of the composed parts of the desired function in reverse order. Did I make a mistake or does the order not matter? I'm not specifically looking to apply this to neural networks. Is the order maybe only relevant if we have a neural network, where we want to update every layer $k$ for which we need $\prod_{i=1}^k \nabla f_{d-i+1}(f^{d-i}(M))$?

More specifically, does this mean the backwards pass can be parallelized to some degree?

Comment: The order would be irrelevant if you deal with reals, but here you deal with matrices...

Comment: Yeah, I know, but would the order of _calculating_ the derivatives matter? By order I don't mean the order of the multiplication. As in, if I have an algorithm I could just save all of the derivatives and then multiply them at the end.

Comment: Oh, wait a second. So that means I can't flip the indices like I do in the fifth line?

Comment: Excuse me, I am not sure I follow correctly your notations...

Comment: Can I improve something about the notation? Is it maybe the $\nabla$ symbol? I used the definition on Wikipedia, I'm not sure if that is standard. $\circ$ is just functional composition.

Comment: Just for clarification, I fixed the multiplication order, I didn't think of that. I'm still not sure if my derivation is correct, but thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Maybe, you can be interested by this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/721172

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't seem to answer my question. The answer doesn't find a closed form. I also need only the first derivative, and how this ties in with automatic differentiation.