# Show that $f(2n)= f(n+1)^2 - f(n-1)^2$

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Let $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$ be the Fibonacci sequence with $f(0)=0,f(1)=1$. Show that $$f(2n)= f(n+1)^2 - f(n-1)^2.$$

I have tried several different approaches to this problem. Both inducting from the rhs and the lhs, and I end up going in circles. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Working from the lhs I've gotten:
$$f(2(n+1)+1)=f(2n+1)+f(2n)$$
$$=f(2n-1) + f(2n) + f(2n)$$
$$=f(2n-1)+2(f(n+1)^2-f(n-1)^2)$$
But I can't figure out where to go from here. Help?

Comment: Brief idea: Come up with an expression for $f(2n+1)$. Then prove that both the expressions for $f(2n)$ and $f(2n+1)$ hold by induction using $f(2(n+1))=f(2n+1)+f(2n)$.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434510/prove-by-induction-for-f2n-fnfn-1-fn1-for-all-n-1

Answer (score 4):

I found a lot of easier to prove the formula using the [matrix representation for the Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number):

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 1 \\ 1 && 0\end{pmatrix}^n = \begin{pmatrix} F_{n+1} && F_n \\ F_n && F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now, matrix multiplication fulfills $A^nA^m=A^{n+m}$, so just calculate the matrix entry $[A^{n+m}]_{1,2}$ and then set $m=n$. The result then follows.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try another proof.

We know that 
$$F_{n+1}=F_{n-1}+F_n\tag{1}$$

There is a useful identity for the Fibonacci sequence. You can look up how it is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11477/showing-that-an-equation-holds-true-with-a-fibonacci-sequence-f-nm-f-n-1).  $$F_{n+m}=F_{n-1}F_m+F_n F_{m+1}\tag{2}$$ Let's set $n=m$, then we get $$F_{2n}=F_nF_{n-1}+F_nF_{n+1}$$
Using (1), we can expand the second expression -
$$F_{2n}=F_nF_{n-1}+F_n(F_n+F_{n-1})$$
$$F_{2n}=2F_nF_{n-1}+F_n^2\tag{3}$$

Now using (1), we try to find a value for the Right Hand side : 
$$F_{n+1}^2= (F_n+F_{n-1})^2 $$$$F_{n+1}^2 = F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2+2F_nF_{n-1}$$ 
$$F_{n+1}^2 - F_{n-1}^2=F_n^2+2F_nF_{n-1}\tag{4}$$

Clearly, (3) and (4) are equal. Hence proved

Answer (score 1):

Let's look for the solutions to the recursive equation in the form $f(n)=C\lambda^n$. If we substitute this form into the recursion we obtain $$\lambda^n=\lambda^{n-1}+\lambda^{n-2},\tag{1}$$ which results in the quadratic equation $$1=\frac{1}{\lambda}+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$$ whose solutions are $$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$ Verify that if $C_1\lambda_1^n$ and $C_2\lambda_2^n$ are solutions of the recursive equation than their sum is a solution as well: $$f(n)=C_1\lambda_1^n+C_2\lambda_2^n,$$

where $C_1=-C_2=\sqrt{5}$ is obtained from the fact that $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=1$ (Use eq. (1))

Now we get $$f(n+1)^2=C_1^2\lambda_1^{2n+2}+C_2^2\lambda_2^{2n+2}+2C_1C_2(\lambda_1\lambda_2)^{n+1}\tag{2}$$
$$f(n+1)^2=C_1^2\lambda_1^{2n-2}+C_2^2\lambda_2^{2n-2}+2C_1C_2(\lambda_1\lambda_2)^{n-1}\tag{3}$$
Subtract (2) and (3) keeping in mind that $\lambda_1\lambda_2=-1$ (from the quadratic equation). We arrive to $$f(n+1)^2-f(n-1)^2=C_1^2\lambda_1^{2n}\left(\lambda_1^2-\frac{1}{\lambda_1^2}\right)+C_2^2\lambda_2^{2n}\left(\lambda_2^2-\frac{1}{\lambda_2^2}\right)$$ Using the values for $C_1$,$C_2$,$\lambda_1$,and $\lambda_2$ we observe that $$C_1\lambda_1^{2n}\left(\lambda_1^2-\frac{1}{\lambda_1^2}\right)=C_2\lambda_2^{2n}\left(\lambda_2^2-\frac{1}{\lambda_2^2}\right)=1$$ and therefore $$f(n+1)^2-f(n-1)^2=C_1\lambda_1^{2n}+C_2\lambda_2^{2n}=f(2n).$$

Comment: Thank you for the proof, but I haven't yet learned about recursive functions. Any chance you thought of an elementary proof while you were at it? Thanks anyways.

Comment: Well, $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$ is a recursive equation :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Binet's Formula?  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html

Comment: I haven't tried Binet's Formula, but we haven't talked about that in class, and it isn't in our book.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Joseph's suggestion, we can prove the identity directly using [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression)
$$f(n) = \frac{\varphi^n - \psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$$
where
$$\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \qquad \psi = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} = -\frac{1}{\varphi}$$
so that
$$\varphi^2 - \frac{1}{\varphi^2} = \sqrt{5} = \frac{1}{\psi^2} - \psi^2 \qquad \varphi\psi - \frac{1}{\varphi\psi} = 0.$$
Then
\begin{align}
f(n+1)^2 - f(n-1)^2 & = \left(\frac{\varphi^{n+1} - \psi^{n+1}}{\sqrt{5}}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{\varphi^{n-1} - \psi^{n-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\right)^2\\
& = \frac{1}{5}\left(\varphi^{2n+2} - 2\varphi^{n+1}\psi^{n+1} + \psi^{2n+2} - \varphi^{2n-2} + 2\varphi^{n-1}\psi^{n-1} - \psi^{2n-2}\right)\\
& = \frac{1}{5}\left(\left(\varphi^2 - \frac{1}{\varphi^2}\right)\varphi^{2n} - 2\left(\varphi\psi - \frac{1}{\varphi\psi}\right)\varphi^n\psi^n - \left(\frac{1}{\psi^2} - \psi^2\right) \psi^{2n}\right)\\
& = \frac{1}{5}\left(\sqrt{5}\varphi^{2n} - 2 \cdot 0 \cdot \varphi^n\psi^n - \sqrt{5}\psi^{2n}\right)\\
& = \frac{\varphi^{2n} - \psi^{2n}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
& = f(2n).
\end{align}