# Is it true that $5^k \mid f(5^k)$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

I guess if it is true that $5^k \mid f(5^k)$, where $f(n)$ denotes the $n$-th Fibonacci's number.
I have tried to prove it by induction on $k$, but nothing. Have you got any ideas?

Comment: Please, please do specify where exactly the Fibonacci sequence starts. Do you define $f(0)=f(1)=1$, or do you define $f(1)=f(2)=1$?

Comment: $f(0)=1, f(1)=1$ so $5\mid f(5)$

Comment: @DanShved $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=1$, $f(3)=2$, $f(4)=3$, $f(5)=5$. If the definition was with $f(0)=f(1)=1$, the assertion would fail at $k=1$.

Comment: Sorry! Your are right, I mean that definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. We have $F_{5} = 5.$ If we write $\sqrt{5}F_{n} = \alpha^{n}-\beta^{n}$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $x^{2}-x-1$ and $\alpha > \beta,$ then it follows by induction that $\alpha^{5^{k}}- \beta^{5^{k}} = \sqrt{5}5^{k} c_{k}$ for some integer $c_{k},$ though the way I see this requires working in the ring of algebraic integers $\mathbb{Z}[\omega],$ where $\omega = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{5}}.$ You seem to want to find your own proof, so I don't give all the details. The key point is that $u^{5} -v^{5} = (u-v) \prod_{i=1}^{4}(u - \omega^{i}v)$ and that $\prod_{i=1}^{4} (1-\omega^{i}) = 5.$

Comment: is it also true that the highest power 5 which divides $f(5^k)$ is $k$?

Comment: @happymath: Yes, I believe that is the case, and you can build that into an inductive proof. The point is that $u - \omega^{i}v \equiv (1- \omega^{i}v)$ (mod $(1- \omega)^{2}$), so the above product is divisible by $(1-\omega)^{4}$ but no higher power of $1- \omega.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ It is *very easy* using the [matrix representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/11482/242) of fibonacci numbers. Then the inductive proof amounts simply to *lifting the exponent* $\,\color{#0a0}{5^k\mapsto 5^{k+1}}\,$ using the Binomial Theorem, e.g.

$$\begin{eqnarray} &&\left[\begin{array}{rr}f_6&f_5\\f_5&f_4\end{array}\right] &=& \left[\begin{array}{rr}8 &5\\5&3\end{array}\right] &=&\, 3I + \color{#0a0}5A\\
\Rightarrow\, &&\left[\begin{array}{rr}f_{26}\!\!&\!\!f_{25}\\f_{25}\!\!&\!\!f_{24}\end{array}\right] &=& \left[\begin{array}{rr}8 &5\\5&3\end{array}\right]^{\large \color{#c00}5} \!\!&=& (3I + 5A)^{\large \color{#c00}5}\! =\, 3^{\large \color{#c00}5} I + {\color{#c00}5}(5A)(\cdots) =\, 3^5 I + \color{#0a0}{5^2} B\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: Very creative! Just to clarify, we use induction to prove that $\left[\begin{matrix}F_{5^k+1} & F_{5^k}\\F_{5^k} & F_{5^k-1}\end{matrix}\right] = 3^{5^{k-1}}I + 5^kA_k$ right? And from this the required result follows by comparing corresponding matrix elements on both sides.

Comment: @Anant Right. The induction step follows simply by taking the fifth power of that equation, as in the example I gave. The key idea is that the representation $\,f_n = (M^n)_{1,2}\,$ as a *power* allows us to use that standard "lifting the exponents" for such powers to lift the congruence up from the base case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the statement is correct, provided the Fibonacci sequence is initialized with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. That is, $f(n)$ is divisible by $5^k$ if and only if $n$ is divisible by $5^k$.

**Hint:** Use the explicit formula for the $n$th term, namely:

> $$f(n)=\frac{\binom n1+5\binom n3+5^2\binom n5+5^3\binom n7+\cdots}{2^{n-1}}.$$

This formula for $f(n)$ can be derived by applying the binomial theorem to the formula

$$f(n)=\frac{(1+\sqrt5)^n-(1-\sqrt5)^n}{\sqrt5\cdot2^n}.$$

Comment: can you please tell how you arrived at this formula