# How to find the remainder of $\dfrac{a_{2011}}{5}$?

Tags: integers

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

> > If $\{a_n\}$ satisfy:
> >     $$a_1=a_2=1$$
> >     $$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_{n}$$
> >      How to find the remainder of $\dfrac{a_{2011}}{5}$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60340/fibonacci-modular-results

Comment: Also, you can adjust the values of $m,n$ in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11477/showing-that-an-equation-holds-true-with-a-fibonacci-sequence-f-nm-f-n-1?lq=1  using $5\mid F_{5n}$