# Find the common divisors of $a_{1986}$ and $a_{6891}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence of integers defined recursively by $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1, a_{n+2} = 4a_{n+1}+a_{n}$ for $n \geq 0$. Find the common divisors of $a_{1986}$ and $a_{6891}$.

I think it is true that $\gcd(a_m,a_n) = a_{\gcd(m,n)}$, but I am not sure how to prove it. From this the answer follows since $\gcd(1986,6891) = 3$ and so $\gcd(a_{1986,6891}) = a_3 = 17$.

Comment: Just pointing out that this reminded me of a putnam problem from last year: A2 2015. Anyway, this is a nice question +1

Answer (score 4):

Your $\,a_i\,$  satisfy the same addition law as the Fibonacci numbers (with the same easy proof as as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/11482/242) using matrix multiplication). Therefore the short proof I gave in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60353/242) shows that this sequence too is a *strong divisibility sequence*, i.e. $\, (a_m,a_n) = a_{\large (m,n)}\,$ which immediately yields the sought result.

**Remark** $\ $ Responding to comments, below are further details. As in the first link we have

$$  \begin{bmatrix}a_2 &a_1\\ a_1 & a_0\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}4 &1\\ 1  & 0\end{bmatrix},\quad \begin{bmatrix} a_{n+2} &\!\!\! a_{n+1}\\ a_{n+1} & \!\!\!a_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_{n+1} &\!\! a_{n}\\ a_{n} & \!\!\!\!a_{n-1}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}4 &1\\ 1  & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus we infer by induction

$$ A_n := \begin{bmatrix} a_{n+1} &\!\! a_{n}\\ a_{n} &\!\!\! a_{n-1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}4 &1\\ 1  & 0\end{bmatrix}^n\! =\, A_1^n $$

Therefore we deduce that $\,A_{m+n} = A_1^{m+n} = A_1^m A_1^n = A_m A_n,\ $ i.e.

$$ \begin{align} \begin{bmatrix} a_{m+n+1} &\!\! a_{m+n}\\ a_{m+n} &\!\!\!\! a_{m+n-1}\end{bmatrix} &=  \begin{bmatrix} a_{m+1} &\!\! a_{m}\\ \!a_{m} & \!\!\!\!a_{m-1}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_{n+1} &\!\! a_{n}\\ a_{n} & \!\!\!\!a_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}\\[.5em]
&= \begin{bmatrix}a_{m+1}a_{n+1}+a_m a_n &\! a_{m+1}a_n+a_m a_{n-1}\\
a_m a_{n+1}+a_{m-1}a_n &\! a_m a_n + a_{m-1} a_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align} $$

This yields the addition law $\ a_{m+n} =\, a_{m+1} a_n +a_m a_{n-1}.\ $ For example

$$ \begin{align} \begin{bmatrix}a_8 & a_7\\ a_7 & a_6\end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}a_4 & a_3\\ a_3 & a_2\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}a_5 & a_4\\ a_4 & a_3\end{bmatrix}\\[.4em]
&=  \begin{bmatrix}72 & \!17\\ 17 &\! 4\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}305 &\!\!\!\!72\\ 72 &\!\!\!\!\! 17\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}23184 &\!\!\! 5473\\ 5473  &\!\!\! 1292\end{bmatrix}
\end{align} $$

---

For $\,f_n = \dfrac{x^n-y^n}{x-y},\,$ satisfying $\,f_{n+2} = \overbrace{(x\!+\!y)}^{f_2} f_{n+1}-xy\, f_n,\,$ a very similar proof shows that it has an analogous  addition law: $\, f_{n+m}\ =\ f_m\ f_{n+1}\,\  -\ xy\, f_{m-1} f_n,\ $ i.e.

$$ \dfrac{x^{n+m}\!-y^{n+m}}{x-y}\,=\, \dfrac{x^{m}\!-y^{m}}{x-y}\,\dfrac{x^{n+1}\!-y^{n+1}}{x-y} - xy\,\dfrac{x^{m-1}-y^{m-1}}{x-y}\,\dfrac{x^{n}-y^{n}}{x-y}\qquad$$

To help dispel doubts in the comments, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=does+%28x%5E%28n%2Bm%29-y%5E%28n%2Bm%29%29%2F%28x-y%29+%3D+%28x%5Em-y%5Em%29%2F%28x-y%29%28x%5E%28n%2B1%29-y%5E%28n%2B1%29%29%2F%28x-y%29-xy%28x%5E%28m-1%29-y%5E%28m-1%29%29%2F%28x-y%29%28x%5En-y%5En%29%2F%28x-y%29%3F) is an Alpha verification of  the prior equation.

Comment: Infinitely more elegant solution. *sigh*

Comment: "same addition law as the fibonacci numbers" ?

Comment: @lhf it is a linear recursion of two variables,  which I think is the main point.

Comment: I don't think this is true. We can write $a_n = \dfrac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}$ where $x = 2+\sqrt{5}$ and $y = 2-\sqrt{5}$. But then http://tinyurl.com/znktgre.

Comment: @user19405892 What don't you think is true?

Comment: What is the addition law? Is it $F_{n+m} = F_{n-1}F_m + F_n F_{m+1}$ because if so I don't agree? The link above contradicts it.

Comment: @user19405892 Why don't you agree?

Comment: Click here tinyurl.com/znktgre.

Comment: @user19405892 What is that supposed prove?  If you examine the proof in the first link I gave you will see exactly the same proof works here (the only difference is that this matrix has $\,M_{1,1} = 4\,$ not $1$, but that does not affect the result).

Comment: Could you write the matrix in the answer?

Comment: @user19405892 For an example of the addition law $$ 5473 = a_{4+3} = a_5 a_3 + a_4 a_2 = 305\cdot 17 + 72\cdot 4$$ If you have any questions about any step in the linked proofs then please let me know.

Comment: @user19405892 I added some details (same as in the first link).

Comment: @lhf I added further details.

Answer (score 0):

Using the characteristic polynomial (you might prove the following by induction)
 we get that $x^{n+2}=4x^{n+1}+x^n$, implying that 
$$a_n=\left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)^{n}+\left(2-\sqrt{5}\right)^n$$
so we can denote this with $\alpha^n+\beta^n.$

We first let $k$ be a nonnegative odd integer, and note that $a_n>0$, and that $\frac{a_kn}{a_n}$ is rational. Then by expanding, we obtain that

$$\frac{a_{kn}}{a_n}=\alpha^{(k-1)n}-\alpha^{(k-2)n}\beta^n+...+\beta^{(k-1)n}$$

which means that $\frac{a_{kn}}{a_n}$ is of the form $a+b\sqrt{5}$. Recalling that it is indeed rational, we get that it must be an integer, so $a_n \vert a_{kn}$.

In the case that $k$ is even,

$$\frac{a_{kn}}{a_n}=\frac{\alpha^{kn}+\beta^{kn}}{\alpha^n+\beta^n}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(-1)^i\cdot\alpha^{k-1-i}\cdot\beta^k+2\beta^k$$

which is again of the form $a+b\sqrt{5}$ so we get a similar argument here.

So, we get that if $m \vert n$, then $a_m \vert a_n$.

Comment: I don't see how "if $m \mid n$, then $a_m \mid a_n$" proves the result.

Comment: It doesnt, it is strictly weaker. You would also need the addition property mentioned in the other answer to prove your last statement. Otherwise, im not certain about how to show that there are no other common divisors.