# Assuming $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1$, and $ a_{n+2} = 4a_{n+1}+a_{n}$ for $n \geq 0$, prove that $\gcd(a_m,a_{m+1}) = \gcd(a_m,a_{m-1})$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence of integers defined recursively by $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1$, and $a_{n+2} = 4a_{n+1}+a_{n}$ for $n \geq 0$. Prove that if $\gcd(a_m,a_{m+1}) = d > 1$, then  $\gcd(a_m,a_{m-1}) = d$ where $m \geq 2$.

It can be shown that if $m|n$, then $a_{m}|a_{n}$. I am wondering if this helps prove the statement or we have to use the Euclidean algorithm to derive it.

Comment: Context for readers: this arises from a proof linked in  [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1867085/242) to the OP's prior question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the recurrence as 
$$
a_{m+1} = 4a_m  +a_{m-1}
$$
Now suppose that $d$ divides both terms on the right. Can you explain why it divides the left?

Comment: OP wants to avoid the Euclidean algorithm, but this uses it - see my comment on Majif's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\gcd(a_m,a_{m-1}) = d$, we have $d|a_m$ and $d|a_{m-1}$. Moreover, according to $a_{n+2} = 4a_{n+1}+a_{n}$, we have $a_{m+1} = 4a_m  +a_{m-1}$. So, it is concluded that:

$$d|a_m\ \ \ \&\ \ \ d|a_{m-1} \rightarrow \ \ d|(4a_m  +a_{m-1})\to \ d|a_{m+1} \to \  d|\gcd(a_m,a_{m+1})$$

Now, assuming $\gcd(a_m,a_{m+1})=d'$, according to $a_{m-1} = -4a_m  +a_{m+1}$, similarly it is concluded that $d'|\gcd(a_m,a_{m-1})=d$.

Thus, we can conclude that $d=d'$.

Comment: OP wants to avoid the Euclidean algorithm, but you are essentially using that, i.e. you are using $\ \color{#c00}{a_{m+1}\equiv a_{n-1}} \pmod{a_m}\ $ so $\ (\color{#c00}{a_{m+1}},a_m) = (\color{#c00}{a_{m-1}},a_n)\,$ by Euclid. Your asnwer just repeats the proof of this gcd equality in this special case.