# For Fibonacci numbers: $\gcd(F_m, F_n) = F_{\gcd(m, n)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, fibonacci-numbers

> Let $(F_n\mid n\in\Bbb N)$ be the Fibonacci sequence. Then $\gcd(F_m, F_n) = F_{\gcd(m, n)}$ for all $m,n\in\Bbb N$.

---

**My attempt:**

**Lemma 1**: $m\mid n\implies F_m\mid F_n$ (A user presented a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/378119/368425))

**Lemma 2**: $F_{m+n}=F_{m-1}F_n+F_mF_{n+1}$ (I presented a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2718270/for-fibonacci-sequence-f-mn1-f-m-f-n-f-m1f-n1-proof-verification))

Let $g=\gcd(m,n)$ and $d$ be any common divisor of $F_m,F_n$. From the definition of Greatest Common Divisor, it's clear that $$\gcd(F_m, F_n) = F_{\gcd(n, m)}=F_g\iff\begin{cases}
F_g\mid F_m\text{ and } F_g\mid F_n\\d\space\space\mid F_g\end{cases}$$

1. $F_g\mid F_m\text{ and } F_g\mid F_n$

Since $g=\gcd(m,n)$, $g\mid m$ and $g\mid n$. From **Lemma 1**, we have $$g\mid m\Rightarrow F_g\mid F_m\quad\hbox{and}\quad
  g\mid n\Rightarrow F_g\mid F_n$$.

2. $d\mid F_g$

From *[Bézout's identity](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)*, there exists $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $g=mx+ny$.

$F_m\mid F_{mx}$ [By **Lemma 1**] and $d\mid F_m\implies d\mid F_{mx}$. Similarly, $d\mid F_{ny}$. Thus $d\mid F_{mx-1}F_{ny}+F_{mx}F_{ny+1}$, and consequently $d\mid F_{mx+ny}$ by **Lemma 2**. Hence $d\mid F_g$.

---

> Does this proof look fine or contain gaps? Do you have suggestions? Many thanks for your dedicated help!

Comment: It looks fine to me. You can look up the properties of Fibonacci numbers and their proofs in the following paper: https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/clancy.pdf

Comment: @Le Cool! If you have done yourself, u have mastered a good amount of identities which contains Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it really fine, apart for a small detail, which you maybe have clear in your mind.

In the last part, $mx$ and/or $ny$ may be negative since the Bézout coefficients $x$ and $y$ are integer numbers. You should prove that there exist $x,y\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $mx+ny=g$.