# Heuristic primality test with an offer $620 for a counterexample

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers, primality-test

There is a heuristic primality test which combine the Fermat test and the Fibonacci test
[(with an offer $620 for a counterexample)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Heuristic_tests):

$(1)\quad 2^{p−1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$
$(2)\quad f_{p+1} \equiv 0 \pmod p$, where $f_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

If $(1)\;\&\;(2)$ are true for a number of the form $p \equiv \pm2 \pmod 5$ then $p$ is supposed to be prime. Due to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Heuristic_tests) the test is *very* efficient, but how to implement $(2)$ efficiently for very big numbers?

Also due to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) there is a method suitable for recursive calculation of $f_n$:

$(3)\quad f_{2n-1}=f_n^2+f_{n-1}^2$
$(4)\quad f_{2n}=f_n\cdot(f_n+2f_{n-1})$

This could be reformulated to calculate $f_n \pmod m$ but is very slow for big numbers.

My question:

> Is there an efficient way to implement $(2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why, sure. Calculation of $f_n$ is not much more complicated than calculation of $2^n$, and can be done by multiplication of $2\times2$ matrices:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}^n\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}f_{n+1}\\ f_n\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Is it fast for $n\approx 10^{100}$ or greater?

Comment: Is $2^n\pmod p$ fast for these $n$? I believe it is. Same thing here.

Comment: @Lehs This imatrix method s very well-known and mentioned here many times in the past, e.g. nine years ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/11482/242), where I remark the same method works for any such recurrence.

Comment: Points to be mentioned are (1) you're not computing $f_n$, you're computing $f_n \mod p$, so huge numbers will not arise, and (2) you're computing powers by repeated squaring, so the complexity is $O(\log n)$.

Comment: Other things to mention is you can reformulate (3) and (4) above into $$f_{4n}=(f_n\cdot(f_n+2f_{n-1}))\cdot((f_n\cdot(f_n+2f_{n-1}))+2(f_n^2+f_{n-1}^2))$$ etc to jump by leaps and bounds.

Answer (score 1):

$$f_{4n}=3\cdot f_n^4 + 8\cdot f_{n-1}\cdot f_n^3 + 6\cdot f_{n-1}^2\cdot f_n^2 + 4\cdot f_{n-1}^3\cdot f_n$$
$$f_{4n-1}=2\cdot f_n^4+4f_{n-1}f_n^3+6f_{n-1}^2f_n^2+f_{n-1}^4$$
If I didn't mess up the expansions (double checked now). You can do this 8 more times, substituting in the formula for the last one you expanded and get to use $f_n$ and $f_{n-1}$ to calculate: $$f_{\tiny{13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084096n}}$$ so $10^{100}$ is no problem as that multiplier alone has 155 digits. You might want to generalize the formula for $f_{y^2 n}$ a bit more to figure out the rest of the difference. but to be fair you asked for values above $10^{100}$ I hope that this at least answers that question from the previous answers comments.

Answer (score 1):

The Heuristic (I think) is likely false and it is rather simple to see.

Let $n = p_1*p_2*...*p_k$ with $k ≥ 5$ odd and assume that for all primes $p | n$:

I. $p^2=4 \pmod 5$

II. $p-1 | n-1$

III. $p+1 | n+1$

Then $n$ is a counterexample to this Heuristic.

Proof:

If condition I is met, then $n=±2 \pmod 5$. If condition II holds, then $n$ is a Carmichael number (it follows from Korselt's criterion), and then $2^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod n$. If the last condition III holds, then for all primes $p|n$, $p=±2 \pmod 5$ so that $f_{p+1} \equiv 0 \pmod p$ and Korselt's criterion can also be generalized here, so that $f_{n+1} \equiv 0 \pmod n$.

Edit/Note: Such a counterexample with these particular properties must have at least 5 prime factors (previously, was assumed 3). See [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X14002108).

Comment: In order for $n$ to be Carmichael, each prime factor $p_i$ must be unique too.  Just thought Id point that out since you didnt mention it. Not sure if/how it impacts your argument.

Comment: I dont fully follow the logic here. Why do you need all $p=\pm 2 (\mod 5)$? Wouldnt one suffice?

Comment: One would suffice (by Fermat's Little Theorem). This decreases the chance of finding a counterexample though. There are only two possibilities with using only one congruence, whereas there are 6 different possibilities if both congruences are simultaneously included.